# django cleaned_data [help]

Tags: python, django, forms

ok so I have the following problem i`ve looked around but I cant find a solution ...

lets say I have the following forms.py

```
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    _username = forms.CharField()
    _password = forms.CharField()
```

and in views.py I have

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    if form.is_valid:
        username = form.cleaned_data['_username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['_password']
        if check_credential(username, password):
            request.session['_username'] = username
            request.session['_password'] = password
```

I`m using 
        void@void:~$ django-admin --version 
        1.1.1

I`m using djangobook to learn django they used an old ver of django that had clean_data ...ive tryed using

```
from django import newforms as forms
```

but the result was the same ...

```
'LoginForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

Answer (score 7):

`form.is_valid` is a function. Use it as

```
if form.is_valid():
    # actions
```

Only after `is_valid()` internally had called each field's own clean method, the form has dict named `cleaned_data`.

Comment: ahhh damn it so this was the problem ... I should`ve read the code more closely ... thx anyway :)

Comment: @void: It is considered good form to accept the answer if the solution worked for you :)